# Android/Eclipse: How to embed .jar file?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, embed, ksoap

I am having trouble embedding a library (ksoap in my case) into my project. There is an error at run time "Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject' referenced from method ...". Of course, this class is available within the ksoap library, no need to mention that i have the respective "import..." lines in my code. I have tried embedding it in different ways that I have found here on stackoverflow and in other places. I tried it via Properties => Build Path => Add external jar and via Import jar, Properties => Build path => Add jar. It does not make a difference and the same happens with other libraries as well. I also tried to choose the Google API or Android as Build Target - however, it does not change.

I am using Eclipse Juno, the Project is an Android 2.2 one. Basically, I have been following the guide at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9EowBVgwSo

See code and complete list of error messages below.

```
package com.example.mytest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
    TextView tv;        
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView01);
        tv.setText("Mein Test");

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Request.addProperty("Celsius", "32");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
            tv.setText("Status: " + resultString);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error messages:

```
10-13 12:59:00.734: E/dalvikvm(6567): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate
10-13 12:59:00.734: W/dalvikvm(6567): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 501 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/example/mytest/FirstScreen;
10-13 12:59:00.734: D/dalvikvm(6567): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012
10-13 12:59:00.734: D/dalvikvm(6567): VFY: dead code 0x0014-005a in Lcom/example/mytest/FirstScreen;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
10-13 12:59:00.875: D/AndroidRuntime(6567): Shutting down VM
10-13 12:59:00.875: W/dalvikvm(6567): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at com.example.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate(FirstScreen.java:25)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-13 12:59:00.875: E/AndroidRuntime(6567):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 12:59:00.878: I/Process(6567): Sending signal. PID: 6567 SIG: 9
10-13 13:03:01.222: E/dalvikvm(6870): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate
10-13 13:03:01.222: W/dalvikvm(6870): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 33 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/example/mytest/FirstScreen;
10-13 13:03:01.222: D/dalvikvm(6870): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012
10-13 13:03:01.222: D/dalvikvm(6870): VFY: dead code 0x0014-005a in Lcom/example/mytest/FirstScreen;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
10-13 13:03:01.472: D/AndroidRuntime(6870): Shutting down VM
10-13 13:03:01.472: W/dalvikvm(6870): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at com.example.mytest.FirstScreen.onCreate(FirstScreen.java:25)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-13 13:03:01.519: E/AndroidRuntime(6870):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried copying the jar simply in the `libs` folder? If the folder does not exist, just create it.

Comment: I guess you are sound enough to add it to libs folder.

Comment: Thanks heaps, it's not enough, but it was the correct approach, see answer below my request.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved the issue thanks to a hint regarding the libs folders.
>
> Thanks to another hint I received I was able to figure out what the problem was. Simply adding the library to the libs folder is not enough - it needs to be added to the build path from that very location as well (Properties => Java Build Path => Add Jars).
>
> That is probably very obvious to those of you familiar with Java/Android developing - but I'm completely new to this stuff. Thanks for the help!